# How can I modify the planningCalendar to show the current Month?

Tags: xml, calendar, sapui5

Pretty straight forward question. For the following [sapUI5 Calendar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar/preview), the example shows the calendar header default display is at December 2015. I've been scouring the API reference but cannot seem to find the property that can adjust this to display the current month. Any ideas?

Here is a full example in [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PVfp3pXWpBmqxPZCwiZK?p=preview)

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sample1.View1"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <PlanningCalendar
            id="PC1"
            startDate="{path: '/startDate'}"
            rows="{path: '/people'}"
            appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect"
            intervalSelect=".handleIntervalSelect">
            <toolbarContent>
                <Title text="Title" titleStyle="H4"/>
            </toolbarContent>
            <rows>
                <PlanningCalendarRow
                    icon="{pic}"
                    title="{name}"
                    text="{role}"
                    appointments="{appointments}"
                    intervalHeaders="{headers}"                 >
                    <appointments>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                            startDate="{start}"
                            endDate="{end}"
                            icon="{pic}"
                            title="{title}"
                            text="{info}"
                            type="{type}"
                            tentative="{tentative}">
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </appointments>
                    <intervalHeaders>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                            startDate="{start}"
                            endDate="{end}"
                            icon="{pic}"
                            title="{title}"
                            type="{type}">
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </intervalHeaders>
                </PlanningCalendarRow>
            </rows>
        </PlanningCalendar>
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a property named "startDate". So, you can call PlanningCalendar.setStartDate(new Date()) somewhere in onInit.